# Grant select on schema in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, permissions

How do I grant select to all items within a schema in PostgreSQL?

I am trying to make a `read-only` user in my PostgreSQL database.  All my tables and views are located within `schema1`.  Sometimes, new views are added within `schema1`, but the read-only user would not have read access to the newly created views.

Is there a way to grant select on all items within a schema so the user has read access to any newly created schemas as well?

My current code is:

```
CREATE ROLE readonly;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE postgres TO readonly;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA schema1 TO readonly;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema1 TO readonly;
```

I know I can add a line to grant select to views in a schema as well, but I am looking for a solution that will work when new views are also added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With event triggers you can handle that :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION auto_grant_func()
RETURNS event_trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE postgres TO readonly;
    GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA schema1 TO readonly;
    GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema1 TO readonly;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER auto_grant_trigger
    ON ddl_command_end
    WHEN TAG IN ('CREATE TABLE', 'CREATE TABLE AS')
EXECUTE PROCEDURE auto_grant_func();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA schema1 GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO readonly;
```

Comment: Looks nice and simple, but does not work for me, does not even make `SELECT` possible on already existing tables.  Are there other conditions to be met?

Comment: Try these ones in addition to the above: GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA schema1 TO readonly;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema1 TO readonly;

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

starting from postgres user. Creating roles. Group exdb1_shared will have select access only, exdb1_devgrp will have full access. Granting accesses to groups only, users from this group would inheritate group acesses.

```
CREATE ROLE exdb1_shared WITH NOLOGIN;
CREATE ROLE exdb1_devgrp WITH NOLOGIN;
CREATE USER exdb1_user;
CREATE USER other_user;
GRANT exdb1_devgrp TO exdb1_user;
GRANT exdb1_shared TO other_user;
```

Now creating DB with postgres user as owner.

```
CREATE DATABASE exdb1 WITH OWNER = postgres;
REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE exdb1 FROM PUBLIC;
```

Connecting to database with postgres user and giving accesses to public to dev group. changelog tables would be stored in public schema, so even if user would be managing another schema, he needs create access to public schema.

```
\connect game_config postgres;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE exdb1 TO exdb1_devgrp;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO exdb1_devgrp;
GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO exdb1_devgrp;
```

Creating schema now and giving accesses. Note that we are still using postgres user, so created schema would be with postgres owner.

```
CREATE SCHEMA shared;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA shared TO exdb1_devgrp;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA shared TO exdb1_devgrp;
```

Now giving access to shared group to schema.

```
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE exdb1 TO exdb1_shared;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA shared TO exdb1_shared;
```

Now last step is to login with user from dev group and give access to exdb1_shared group to have select access on tables created later.

```
\c exdb1 exdb1_user;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA shared GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO exdb1_shared;
```

From now other_user user should have SELECT access to all tables created by exdb1_user. Feel free to give feedback, not sure that this solution is the only one.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).